# BASH: Replacing special character groups

Tags: oracle, bash, replace, special-characters

I have a rather tricky request...

We use a special application which is connected to a oracle database. For control reasons the application uses special characters which are defined by the application and saved in a long field of the database.

My task is to query the long field periodically and check for changes. To do that, I write the content by using a bash script in a file and compare the old and the new file with md5sum.

When there's a difference, I want to send the old file via mail. The problem is, that the old file contains these special characters and I don't know how to replace them with for example a string which describes them.

I tried to replace them on the basis of their ASCII code, but this didn't work. I've also tried to replace them by their appearance in the file. (They look like this: ^P ) This didn't work neither.

When viewing the file by text editor like nano the characters are visible like described above. But when using cat on the file, the content is only displayed until the first appearance of such a control character.

As far as I know there is know possibility to replace them while querying from the database because of the fact that the content is in a LONG field.

I hope you can help me.

Thank you in advance.

Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xxd` to change the string to its hex representation, then use `xxd -r` to convert back.

Or, you can use `uuencode` and `uudecode`.

Comment: Okay. Now I know the hex codes of the characters. But how do I use this information? The codes are 0x10, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14 and 0x16.

Comment: @MarcoFrost: Now you can `mail` the output. The addressee can run `xxd -r` to get the original file back. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Probably I didn't explain my request very well. I want to replace the special characters mentioned above in the file I create from the LONG-Field of the Database. The special characters have the hex codes 0x10, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14 and 0x16.

Comment: @MarcoFrost: Ah. Replace with what?

Comment: With strings which describe the replaced chars.

Comment: Something like `perl -pe 's/([\0-\11\13-\37])/"[".ord($1)."]"/ge' file`?

Comment: I did it like this `sed 's/\x10/[*]/g' | sed 's/\x13/[>]/g' | sed 's/\x12/[=]/g'`

Comment: @MarcoFrost: Note that you do not need to run `sed` 3 times: `sed 's///g;s///g;s///g` or, if not supported, `sed -e 's///g' -e 's///g'`.

Comment: Thank you! `sed 's/\x15/[!]/g;s/\x10/[*]/g;s/\x13/[>]/g;s/\x12/[=]/g;s/\x16/[and]/g;s/\x14/[<]/g'`

Answer (score 2):

`^P` is the Control-P character, which is decimal 16 or hexadecimal 0x10, also known as the Data Link Escape (DLE) character in ASCII.

To replace all occurrences of 0x10 in a file with another string we can use our friend `gsed`:

```
gsed "s/\x10/Data Link Escape/g" yourfile.txt
```

This should replace all occurrences of characters containing the hex value 0x10 with the text string "Data Link Escape".  You'll probably want to use a different string - this is just an example.

Depending on the system you're using you may be able to use the standard `sed` command if your version of `sed` recognizes the `\xNN` single-character escape codes.  If there are multiple hex characters you need to replace you may want to create a file containing your `sed` commands, one for each hexadecmial character you need to replace, and tell `sed` or `gsed` to use the commands in the file - consult the `sed` or `gsed` man pages for how to do this.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Together with help @choroba I was able to manipulate the database query stream with sed to replace the characters I was talking of. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to run the file through `cat -v`. This replaces nonprinting characters with visible representations (using the `^` notation for control characters):

```
$ echo $'\x10\x12\x13\x14\x16' | cat -v
^P^R^S^T^V
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But I really want to replace the characters with explanations of them.